# Best practice for reading/writing and accessing settings (not using windows settings)

Tags: c#, xml

First thing to say is that I can't use built in Properties.Settings, as these settings are stored in an XML file which are used by several people (not at the same time but via version control).

I am developing a code generation tool which allows the users to specificy the output locations of all the generated files, along with other project specific settings.

Currently, in the application I have a static class called ProjectSettings which has a public static parameter for each setting using the in program:

```
public static string Settings_ScreenDefinitions_C;
public static string Settings_ScreenDefinitions_H;
// Etc currently there are about 20 of these.
```

Is there a better way of storing and accessing these thoughout the project?

Secondly these settings are stored in an XML using a read/write call for each setting in the above ProjectSettings class:

```
xmlWriter.WriteElementString("ScreenDefinitionsFileC", ProjectSettings.Settings_ScreenDefinitions_C);
xmlWriter.WriteElementString("ScreenDefinitionsFileH", ProjectSettings.Settings_ScreenDefinitions_H);
// Again there is around 20 of these, one for each property and the same for reading them back out.
```

As I add more properties I can't help but feel that there must be a more elegant way of constructing the class (maybe a dictionary?) and a better way of using that within the XML for saving and reading?

Any suggestions/pointers would be great.

Comment: Depending on your choice, you can use app settings `Properties.Settings`,  an `ini` file, xml file, or a serialized object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it with an enum and a dictionary. I've used console output to show how you can write the key and value of the dictionary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        private enum Settings
        {
            ScreenDefinitionsFileC,
            ScreenDefinitionsFileH
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var settings= new Dictionary<Settings, string>()
            {
                {Settings.ScreenDefinitionsFileC, "Setting 1"},
                {Settings.ScreenDefinitionsFileH, "Setting 2"}
            };


            foreach (var setting in settings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", setting.Key, setting.Value);
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can enumerate your settings when writing to XML, but can also look-up specific settings during the life cycle of your program.

Comment: Thanks this looks much tidier and easier to expand. I'll probably update my application to use something like this. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem @TheGrovesy glad it can be of use :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I don't know the whole list of the configurations, but I hope most of them may be controlled by adding different configuration in configurationManger, that is if you add "MyConfiguration" you can open afterwards project settings (especially pre-build and post build event)and the configurations there are all only for "myConfiguration" so switching between different configurations is only by selecting different configuration.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question... or maybe its poorly written :S